# CFL that runs in NP-time

Tags: formal-languages, runtime-analysis, np

What is an example of a context-free language that runs in NP-time? I've done searches but cant find one. Frankly, I do not know how to determine when a CFL is P or NP. Can someone tell me, please?

Comment: What do you mean by NP time? NP does not stand for non polynomial. It means non deterministic polynomial, which includes polynomial time.

Answer (score 3):

All context free languages can be recognized in polynomial time:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm

Comment: Yes, I know, but I'm trying to prove that a CFL is a proper subset of polynomial time

Comment: @matttm : ​ That's completely unrelated to what you asked. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: My method of proof was to show a cfl exists in NP.

Comment: You mean P? If you want to show that it's polynomial, you need to show that every CFL is in P. Don't forget, NP is a superset of P, so every CFL is in NP.